# Equivalent of pstricks command \psecurve in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

What is the equivalent of the `pstricks` command `\psecurve` in `tikz`?

The yellow line is the `\psecurve`.  It's basically the same as the `\pscurve`: the curve is defined by all the named points, but is not drawn to the end points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-3)(5,5)
   \pscurve[linewidth=5pt,arrows=<->](0,0)(2,3)(4,-3)(2,5)(1,0)
  \psecurve[linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=yellow](0,0)(2,3)(4,-3)(2,5)(1,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use my `style between` style (from [TikZ: Thick curve segment in a curve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88379/14500)):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\newcounter{pos}
\tikzset{
  initcounter/.code={\setcounter{pos}{0}},
  style between/.style n args={3}{
    postaction={initcounter, decorate,
      decoration={show path construction, curveto code={
          \addtocounter{pos}{1}
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\min}{#1 - 1}
          \ifthenelse{\thepos < #2 \AND \thepos > \min}{
            \draw[#3]
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
               (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
            .. (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
          }{}
        }
      }
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
  \draw[line width=5pt,<->]
  (0,0) to[out=70,in=180] (2,3) to[out=0,in=180] (4,-3)
  to [out=0,in=0] (2,5) to[out=180,in=100] (1,0);

  \path [style between={2}{4}{line width=1.5pt,yellow}]
  (0,0) to[out=70,in=180] (2,3) to[out=0,in=180] (4,-3)
  to [out=0,in=0] (2,5) to[out=180,in=100] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works at all?

Comment: @A.Ellett Look at the `show path construction` decoration into the pgf manual.

Comment: That's what I've been doing.  It still looks like magic to me.

Comment: The default arrow head of TikZ is not as sharp as that of PSTricks. (But it is not the point here)

Comment: @GarbageCollector `TikZ \neq PSTricks`. You may use `>=stealth`...