# Is there a way to specify style for part of a path in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-path

When I need a partially dashed path as below

[image: partially dashed]

I have to write two `\draw` commands:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0)--(1,1);
        \draw[dashed] (1,1)--(1,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That is basically OK, but can the job be finished in a single `\draw` command?

I have tried

```
%\draw (0,0)--(1,1)[dashed]--(1,2);   % dashes both segments
%\draw (0,0)--(1,1){[dashed]--(1,2)}; % no effect
%\draw (0,0)--(1,1){[dashed]--}(1,2); % fails
```

but they either fail or do not work as desired.

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300919/tikz-is-it-possible-to-change-line-style-within-same-draw-command

Comment: @GiuTeX OK. I have tried `edge` and that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\section{Not wanted}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
 \draw[dashed] (1,1)--(1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{You can use the edge syntax}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) edge[dashed] (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So different styles are not intended to be mixed in a single path. Thanks.

Comment: I think so. I edited, because I do not know how to use "edge" several times in one path at this moment.